# How can I click on button on another application using winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

I find in this forum something like:

```
SendMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Ok, but how Can I get ButtonHandle? I think I have to use FindWindowEx, but how do that? I know how get handle to window, not to widget which is his child.

For example my other application title is "example". The button which I would like to click is "button1" and his text is "click me". How can I click it?

Comment: FindWindowEx allow to search for the childs of a window and by iterating its full child arbo. And once you have a window, you can query its text. No as simple as one could expect, but in the end you find your window....

Comment: Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). As for identifying the target window, you're going to have to find a unique feature (or combination of features) and use that, for example, in your `EnumWindows` callback.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you. Do you have any snippet with this?

Comment: Unless the button is a *direct* child of the target window, then you have to enumerate through the window's child AND grandchild controls recursively until you find the button. Use a tool like Spy++ to see the actual parent/child hierarchy of the desired window, and then make calls to `FindWindowEx()` accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you :) I know about Spy++, but now I have very simple application with only one main window and one button on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FindWindowExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa): The function searches child windows, beginning with the one following the specified child window.

So I recommend you to use it like this:

`HWND ButtonHandle = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, NULL, TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Your button name"));`